# Optimize map within a loop

Tags: ruby

I have a dataset that is an array of hashes

```
[
  {:last_name=>"Smith", :first_name=>"John", :city=>"New York City", :birthdate=>"5/29/1986"},
  {:last_name=>"Bar", :first_name=>"Foo", :city=>"Chicago", :birthdate=>"5/29/1986"},
  ...
]
```

I want to print the values in a specific order. Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
def print(dataset, select_fields)
  output = ''
  dataset.each do |set|
    output += select_fields.map { |key| set[key] }.join(' ') + "\n"
  end
  puts output
end
```

Because I'm calling `map` within `each` I believe this is pretty slow. Maybe O(n²) slow?

Is there any way to optimize this? Using Ruby 2.2.1

Comment: You're probably obsessing over nothing here - unless this is all your app does it's very unlikely to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my print is about 30%  faster on my machine. I'm pretty sure there are guys who can make it much faster than I did. In general try to iterate over a specific array once. Btw - when you are testing code, avoid any puts, because it slows your tests tremendously.

```
set = [
  {:last_name=>"Smith", :first_name=>"John", :city=>"New York City", :birthdate=>"5/29/1986"},
  {:last_name=>"Bar", :first_name=>"Foo", :city=>"Chicago", :birthdate=>"5/29/1986"},
]

def my_print(dataset, select_fields)  
  output = ''
  dataset.each do |set|
    select_fields.each do |sf|
      output << "#{set[sf]} "
    end
    output[-1] = "\n"
  end  
  output
end

def your_print(dataset, select_fields)
  output = ''
  dataset.each do |set|
    output += select_fields.map { |key| set[key] }.join(' ') + "\n"
  end
  output  
end

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report do
    1_000_000.times do
      my_print(set, [:first_name, :last_name])
    end
  end
end

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report do
    1_000_000.times do
      your_print(set, [:first_name, :last_name])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Since he wants to print it, you could already make it faster by not concatenating it into a string. Just print every line as it comes up.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you could do the following.

```
def print(dataset, select_fields)
  dataset.each { |h,a| puts h.values_at(*select_fields).join(' ') }
end
```

See [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: No need to use `each_with_object`.Why not just `each`?

Comment: @Caspar, thanks. I've edited. `each_with_object` was a relic from  different approach  I took initially.